# Bootstrap Tags Input plugin is not working on first type

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, bootstrap-tags-input

I have an HTML page with a text field for getting tags. I used ***Bootstrap tags input*** to get all desired tags. It works fine. But the problem is that: **It is not working on first type!**

Here is my code:

```html
<head>
        <title></title>
    
    
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/twitter-bootstrap/3.3.5/css/bootstrap.min.css">
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/twitter-bootstrap/3.3.5/css/bootstrap-theme.min.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://bootstrap-tagsinput.github.io/bootstrap-tagsinput/dist/bootstrap-tagsinput.css">
        
    
    
    
    </head>
    <body>
    <input type="text" id="Tags" class="form-control"/>
        
        <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.4/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://bootstrap-tagsinput.github.io/bootstrap-tagsinput/dist/bootstrap-tagsinput.min.js"></script>
        
        <script>
          $(document)
                .on('keypress',
                    '#Tags',
                    function (event) {
                        if (event.keyCode == 13) {
                            event.preventDefault();
                        }
                        $(this).tagsinput({
                            confirmKeys: [13, 32, 44]
                        });
                    });
        </script>  
        
        
    </body>
```

When I try to type in the text field, It wont type and resizes text field. But again, after focusing on same text field I will be able to type.

https://jsfiddle.net/AfsanehDaneshi/p525yuyk/

Comment: Try wrapping your tags code in `$(function(){ ...  });`

Answer (score 0):

You do not need to use a custom handler with the `tagsInput` library.

You can just use the following:

```
$('#Tags').tagsinput({
   confirmKeys: [13, 32, 44]
});
```

See [updated jsFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/p525yuyk/1/)

Comment: The reason I used this custom handler was, because I am loading a partial-view after document.load event and if I use your code, tags Input is not working anymore.

Comment: @ZDaneshi So you are inserting the input field dynamically after the DOM is rendered?

Answer (score 0):

use "keyup" instead of "keypress"
It works fine!

Answer (score 0):

I got the same problem. Here is my solution :

**HTML**

```
<div id="div-tags">
     <input type="text" id="tags" name="tags" data-role="tagsinput" />
</div>
```

**JavaScript**

```
$('#tags').on('itemAdded', function(event) { 
     $('#div-tags .bootstrap-tagsinput .tag').css('display','inline'); 
});
```